# Catch the start applications

Tags: delphi, winapi, process

How to catch the start and completion of applications (processes) in Win. 
How to measure the time of each application?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to get timing information for a particular process.

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessTimes(
  __in   HANDLE hProcess,
  __out  LPFILETIME lpCreationTime,
  __out  LPFILETIME lpExitTime,
  __out  LPFILETIME lpKernelTime,
  __out  LPFILETIME lpUserTime
);
```

See this example

```
program GetProcessTime;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  DateUtils,
  Windows,
  tlhelp32,
  SysUtils;


Procedure  GetAllProcessTime;
var
  HandleSnapShot   : THandle;
  EntryParentProc  : TProcessEntry32;
  DummyCreateFileTime : Windows.FILETIME;
  DummyExitFileTime   : Windows.FILETIME;
  DummyKernelFileTime : Windows.FILETIME;
  DummyUserFileTime   : Windows.FILETIME;
  aFileName           : String;
  h                   : THandle;
  ActualTime          : TDateTime;
  Dif                 : TDateTime;
  CreationTime        : TDateTime;


function FileTime2DateTime(FileTime: TFileTime): TDateTime;    //Convert then FileTime to TDatetime format
var
  LocalTime: TFileTime;
  DOSTime  : Integer;
begin
  FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTime, LocalTime);
  FileTimeToDosDateTime(LocalTime, LongRec(DOSTime).Hi, LongRec(DOSTime).Lo);
  Result := FileDateToDateTime(DOSTime);
end;

begin
  HandleSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);  //get the list of process
  if HandleSnapShot <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    EntryParentProc.dwSize := SizeOf(EntryParentProc);
    if Process32First(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc) then   //Get the first process in the list
    begin
      Writeln( Format('%-30s %-20s %-16s',['FileName','Start','Running Time'])  );
      ActualTime:=Now;
      repeat
          h:=OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,false,EntryParentProc.th32ProcessID);  //open a particular process
          if GetProcessTimes(h, DummyCreateFileTime, DummyExitFileTime, DummyKernelFileTime, DummyUserFileTime) then  //get the timing  info
          begin
            aFileName:=ExtractFileName(EntryParentProc.szExeFile);
            CreationTime:=FileTime2DateTime(DummyCreateFileTime); //get the initial time of the process
            Dif :=  ActualTime-CreationTime; //calculate the elapsed time
            Writeln( Format('%-30s %-20s %-16s',[aFileName,FormatDateTime('DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN:SS',CreationTime),FormatDateTime('HH:NN:SS',Dif)])  );
          end;
          CloseHandle(h);
      until not Process32Next(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc);
    end;
    CloseHandle(HandleSnapShot);
  end;

end;



begin
  try
    GetAllProcessTime();
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
     Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
     Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple or so Windows API calls with 'hook' in the name that allow you to capture systemwide events. You'll have to build those into a DLL, and then make calls to the 'hooking' DLL from a separate application.

That, VERY briefly, is it. Hope that gets you started!

Answer (score 1):

the [WH_CBT hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx) is most likely the one you are after.  It allows you to be notified by the OS whenever a window is created or destroyed.  You will want to use this hook to grab the handle and from the handle get the process id using [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx).  You can then pass this handle to the function [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223(VS.85).aspx) (suggested by RRUZ) to get the times.  An example (although dated, the concepts are still the same) is available in the [GpSysHook](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/gpsyshook.htm) source.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Performance Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305187.aspx) has features specifically for timing applications from the moment they start, even if they're in the boot or log-in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Management Instrumentation offers event subscription. The nice thing with WMI is that it works remote too, using DCOM and SOAP.

[WMI offers the capability to notify a subscriber for any event it is interested in.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#Features)

> WMI uses the WMI Query Language (WQL)
>   to submit WQL event queries and
>   defines the type of events to be
>   returned. The eventing mechanism, with
>   all related callbacks, is part of the
>   WMI COM/DCOM and automation
>   interfaces.

A free WMI client implementation for Delphi is available online (not sure if it supports event callbacks):

[Magenta Systems WMI and SMART Component](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp)